# How to capture apache proxypass response time??

Tags: apache, httpresponse, proxypass

%t and %d are the tokens in apache logs for response time . Is there any way to get the response time ?? 
My idea is to pass response time as variable in error document redirection .

```
 </> 
   ErrorDocument /test.py?response_time= %t or %d 
  <proxypass>....</proxypass> 
  <proxyreverse>....</proxyreverse> 
 </>
```

Any kind off alternative solution will accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set in the logformat? 
like this
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %D"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html